# Changing dependencies on runtime in phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I was creating a web-app in [phoenix](http://www.phoenixframework.org/), It creates a folder of dependencies called `deps`, I wanted to know If I can change code of one of the dependencies and see How it affects. I tried to do it, but it doesn't executes my injected code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you recompile the dependencies?

From the command line of your directory, after you make the change, issue the command

```
mix deps.compile
```

This should cause your code changes to be included.

Comment: Sometimes you have to delete the relevant directory under `_build/` directory to force it to build. I had to do it for `_build/test/mailgun`.